# Issue with DB2 DELETE COMMAND

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete

I have a `SQL table` with `column A & B`
and I have a requirement to delete data from a corresponding DB2 table whose column values are not same as the above mentioned sql table.. I have implemented something like below to achieve this functionality.

RSSQL.Open `"select * from sql_table"`

> ConnDB2 `"DELETE from db2_table where not exists(select 1 from
>   db2_table d where d.A='" & rssql.fields(0) & "' and d.B = '"&
>   rssql.fields(1) &"')`

but this delete command is not able to delete any values in the db2 table. Please help.

SQL TABLE:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B
12          23
34          56
```

DB2 TABLE:

```
COLUMN A  COLUMN B
1             2
12           23
3             4
34           56
```

So, My delete command should delete first and third row. Post delete, the db2 table should look like below:

DB2 TABLE:

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B
12            23
34            56
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, can you provide a sample table with some data that illustrates the problem. Your problem seems generic so you should be able to use sqlfiddle with some DBMS other than DB2

Comment: @lennart : I have added the sample tables and out put . can u help now

Comment: Are these tables present in two different DB servers ?

Comment: @Utkarsh : yes. first table is sql table. second one is db2 table. i have to delete data from db2 table based on its column values which should not match with sql table's column value

Comment: SQL is a language, with different implementations from different companies - DB2 (from IBM) is one of these.  What exactly did you mean by SQL Table (which other company)?  Note that you may have the easiest time bulk-loading the other table into DB2, then running the statement from Gordon's answer there.  Also, you should be using some form of parameterized query, as you may be open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the `delete` that you want:

```
delete from db2_table dt
    where not exists (select 1
                      from sql_table st
                      where st.columna = dt.columna and st.columnb = dt.columnb
                     );
```

I'm not sure why you are executing two queries.

Comment: She says tables are in two different servers. Will this work using single db connection ?

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, I did not try this, though i had this in my mind. one question:, can we combine sql and db2 queries together (like what you did in ur answer) because the connection object is of DB2. How will my subquery execute since it is connecting to sql and not db2.

Comment: @ArpitaDutta - As far as I know, you couldn't do that.

Comment: @Utkarsh : then can u suggest an alternate option?the sample code snippet which i have pasted in my query, is not working. is my approach correct. if so, then what am i missing here?

Comment: @ArpitaDutta  - Well, It can be done using programming languages ( like java etc).  You can get the results from sqltable using one connection and then you can use the previously received results and use it in next query using another connection. I don't know how you are trying to achieve this using SQL commands on DB console. Are you using any programming language ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Perhaps you could explain _why_ the original query isn't working?  And how close to disaster the original statement comes?

Comment: @ArpitaDutta . . . I think IBM has products to connect to other databases.  This might be a reasonable place to start:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504zikopoulos/.